# How to close message dialog programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I have a question about joptionpane.

Using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...), we can create a message dialog. But how to close it programmatically?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could always get a reference to the JOptionPane by getting the WindowAncestor of any component it's holding, and then call `dispose()` or `setVisible(false)` on the Window returned. The Window can be obtained by using `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component)`

For example:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CloseOptionPane {

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JLabel label = new JLabel();
      int timerDelay = 1000;
      new Timer(timerDelay , new ActionListener() {
         int timeLeft = 5;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timeLeft > 0) {
               label.setText("Closing in " + timeLeft + " seconds");
               timeLeft--;
            } else {
               ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
               Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(label);
               win.setVisible(false);
            }
         }
      }){{setInitialDelay(0);}}.start();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Can someone deduct marks from this one, LOL, I don't think so +1 for this nicely crafted example :-)

Comment: Thanks. The key though is call all necessary code before the JOptionPane is shown.

Comment: using an embedded component as a hook - nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

If you add `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)`  in a While loop use `return` to close it.

If you add `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)`  try catch block it close when exception happen.

```
try {
                
    }
catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Inputs");             
        }
```