# I'm using JOptionPane to get user input and display a message. Is there a way for the input and message windows to both close when OK is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

When the program runs, it shows a window filling up with tiny (5x5) rectangles of various colors, with the red and green RGB values corresponding to the rectangles' position on the screen. The blue RGB value is random but applies to all the rectangles. I ask the user with an input dialog to guess the random value, then I use a message dialog to tell them how far off they are. Here's the program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoColorSpectrum extends Applet {  
public void paint(Graphics squares) {   
    squares.setColor(Color.white);
    squares.fillRect(0, 0, 1280, 750);

    Random rectStr = new Random();
    int randomRed,
        randomGreen,
        randomBlue,
        randomX,
        randomY,
        rectNum;
    do {
        rectNum = rectStr.nextInt(9999999);
    } while(rectNum < 5000000);

    Random color3 = new Random();
            randomBlue = color3.nextInt(255);

    for(int h = 1; h <= rectNum; h++) {
        Random xPosition = new Random(); 
            randomX = xPosition.nextInt(1275);
            double pcx = randomX / 1275.0;
            double dRandomR = pcx * 255.0;
            randomRed = (int)(dRandomR);

        Random yPosition = new Random();
            randomY = yPosition.nextInt(745);
            double pcy = randomY / 745.0;
            double dRandomG = pcy * 255.0;
            randomGreen = (int)(dRandomG);

        Color randomColor = new Color(randomRed, randomGreen, randomBlue);
        squares.setColor(randomColor);
        squares.fillRect(randomX, randomY, 4, 4);
    }

    //asking the user what blue value it is
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a value from 0 to 255.");
    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Am I right?");
    final int WIDTH = 350;
    final int HEIGHT = 100;

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str;
            int num;

            str = field.getText();
            num = Integer.parseInt(str);
            int absOff = Math.abs((randomBlue - num));

            if(absOff != 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You were " + absOff
                                              + " off! The blue value is "
                                              + randomBlue + ".", "How much "
                                              + "were you off?", 
                                              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } 
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That's right! The blue "
                                              + "value is " + randomBlue
                                              + ".", "How much " + "were you off?",
                                               JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Guess the Color!");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    panel.add(button);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

How can I make it so that the message dialog only shows up once, then disappears when the OK button is pressed?

Comment: Lets start with [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) then ask the question why you're creating a `JFrame` from within an applet anyway?

Comment: Oh dear ..., DON'T put all your programs logic in the paint method, paint is for painting, nothing else

Comment: [How to close message dialog programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860731/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically)