# How to make my JOptionPane dialogue box disappear after 10 seconds

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have a method in Java to catch exception and show in a dialogue box . I would like to make the dialogue box only for 10 seconds and should disappear after that . My code is below

```
private void errorpopup(Exception m)
{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
              null,
              new JLabel("<html><body><p style='width: 300px;'>"+m.toString()+"</p></body></html>", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));

}
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component)** is a method that returns the first ancestor window of the component.

You can use this in conjunction with your JLabel (as the component) to get a reference to the JOptionPane Message Dialog Window which you could then close within a timer method set to 10 seconds; something like so:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        errorpopup(new Exception("Error"));
    }

    private static void errorpopup(Exception m)
    {
        JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("<html><body><p style='width: 300px;'>"+m.toString()+"</p></body></html>");
        Timer timer = new Timer(10000, 
            new ActionListener()
            {   
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(messageLabel).dispose();
                }
            });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messageLabel, "Error Window Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this link has another example of how it could be done:
[How to close message dialog programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860731/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically)

You would need to do a little bit of work to make it fit your purpose but it shows how you could display the countdown to the user which is neat.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13344556)

Comment: @HunterTurner In this case flagging as a duplicate would be the correct course of action, not copying the answer.

Comment: How do I do that? EDIT: I'm assuming I'm lacking privileges to do that.

Comment: There should be a "flag"  option under the question.

Comment: There's not. I only have 7 rep so I assume that option will appear in future.

Comment: Use a Swing timer instead. See the link I gave to the OP.